# Proof for the Rodrigues formula for Neumann's Spherical functions.

Tags: special-functions

I've been trying to prove the Rodrigues formula for Neumann's Spherical functions.
The Neumann's Spherical functions are:
$$N_n(x))=-(-x)^n\left[\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\right]^n\frac{\cos{(x)}}{x}$$

As a guide, I followed the derivation of the Rodrigues formula for Legendre's Polynomials (for reference, view http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~fry/6346/legendre.pdf), yet I don't seem to be getting anywhere.